# How to create catkin_ws?

Tags: ros, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS using [conda environment](https://medium.com/robostack/cross-platform-conda-packages-for-ros-fa1974fd1de3). How can I find main directory of ROS? I used command "roscd", but I got following result:  C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\envs\gz-postinstall\Library> Here "gz-postinstall" is environment created for gazebo installation, which I plan to use with ROS. My question is How to create catkin_ws and where?

OS Windows 10 x64
ROS noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372755/how-to-create-catkin_ws?/) by [Grigoriy_Y](https://answers.ros.org/users/70870/grigoriy_y/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not know much about anaconda environment. But you should be able to create a ROS workspace anywhere except restricted files that are block by the system.

---

Originally posted by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) with karma: 98 on 2021-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grigoriy_Y](https://answers.ros.org/users/70870/grigoriy_y/) on 2021-06-25**:
Thank you!